# How to get every parameters and their value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.web

I use the following function:

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString
```

I'm able to extract one parameter value so far. However now I'd like if possible to obtain all parameters in an array, and another array with all their value. Is there a way to do this?

For one parameter value I do this:

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get(param)
```

In the worst case, if I can't have an array for both, if I could get a `string array` for the parameters, I could then use the line above with every parameters to get the value.

Comment: `Request.QueryString'

Comment: I'm not sure how I write it? it's a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get dictionary of parameters and then get each parameter value.

```
string uri = "http://www.example.com?param1=good&param2=bad";
string queryString = new System.Uri(uri).Query;

var queryDictionary = System.Web.HttpUtility
                            .ParseQueryString(queryString);

var paramsList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var parameter in queryDictionary)
{
     var key = (string) parameter;
     var value = queryDictionary.Get(key);
     paramsList.Add(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<br />");
foreach (String s in qscoll.AllKeys)
{
    sb.Append(s + " - " + qscoll[s] + "<br />");
}

ParseOutput.Text = sb.ToString();
```

So the result of ParseQueryString is a Dictionary, which holds all parsed data, just iterate through it :)

Comment: I voted it up, thanks!! However I will vote the other one as answer soon because I found it easier. I really appreciate your help though thanks :)